# combining values from mysql seperated by comma using explode

Tags: php, mysql

I have two columns in my mysql table `pro_id` and `pro_page`. Each column contains integer values separated by comma.

example,

```
 pro_id      pro_page
--------   ------------
 1,2,3        1,1,1
   2            1
  3,4          2,1
```

I want to combine first integer value from `pro_id` and first integer value from `pro_page`, second integer value from `pro_id` and second integer value from `pro_page` and so on.

For example,

from first row, result should be 11 21 31

from second row, result should be 21

from third row, result should be 32 41

I have tried using the below code,

```
$query  =   "SELECT pro_id, pro_page from tbl_checkout";
$result =   mysqli_query($c,$query)or die(mysqli_error($c));
$length =   mysqli_num_rows($result);
while($row  =   mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
    $pro_id[] = $row["pro_id"];
    $pro_page[] = $row['pro_page'];
}

for($i=0; $i<$length1; $i++)
{
    $pro_id = explode(",", @$pro_id[$i]);
    $pro_page = explode(",", @$pro_page[$i]);

    foreach($pro_id as $product_id) {
        $product_id = $product_id;
        echo $product_id;
    }
    foreach($pro_page as $product_page) {
        echo $product_page;
    }
}
```

Now the result is,

from first row, 123111

from second row, 21

from third row, 3421

Is there any way to achieve what i want. I have tried a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via single `foreach` if you numbers amount is same in both arrays

```
$products = explode(",", @$pro_id[$i]);
$pages = explode(",", @$pro_page[$i]);

foreach( $products as $k => $product_id){

    $product_page = $pages[$k];
    echo $product_id . $product_page . " ";
}
```

Comment: Won't work as `$pro_id[] = $row["pro_id"]` and `$pro_id = explode(",", @$pro_id[$i]);` will mess up.

Comment: @mexhb agree updating

Answer (score 3):

After fetching the array from database do the following:

```
$output = array();
while($row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
    $pro_id = explode(',' , $row["pro_id"]);
    $pro_page = explode(',' , $row['pro_page']);
    for($i = 0; $i< count($pro_id); $i++)
    {
        $output[$i] = $pro_id[$i] . $pro_page[$i];
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop over both arrays at once. Easiest when using `for()`:

```
$query  =   "SELECT pro_id, pro_page from tbl_checkout";
$result =   mysqli_query($c,$query)or die(mysqli_error($c));
$length =   mysqli_num_rows($result);
while($row  =   mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
    $pro_id[] = $row["pro_id"];
    $pro_page[] = $row['pro_page'];
}

for($i=0; $i<$length1; $i++)
{
    // don't assign to $pro_id and $pro_page as variable name: it will mess up your data!
    $tmp_id = explode(",", $pro_id[$i]);
    $tmp_page = explode(",", $pro_page[$i]);

    for($c=0; $c < count($tmp_id)) {
        echo $tmp_id[$c];
        echo $tmp_page[$c];
    }
}
```

Another problerm is that you use `$pro_id` and `$pro_page` for two different purposes. You use it for storage of db results **and** to store the exploded numbers from this data. Use different variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
$query  =   "SELECT pro_id, pro_page from tbl_checkout";
$result =   mysqli_query($c,$query)or die(mysqli_error($c));
$length =   mysqli_num_rows($result);
while($row  =   mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
{
  $pro_id[] = $row["pro_id"];
  $pro_page[] = $row['pro_page'];
}

for($i=0; $i<$length1; $i++){
  $pro_id = explode(",", @$pro_id[$i]);
  $pro_page = explode(",", @$pro_page[$i]);

    $newProduct_id = '';
    foreach($pro_id AS $keyIndex => $product_id) {
        $newProduct_id = $pro_id[$keyIndex] . $pro_page[$keyIndex] . " ";
        echo $newProduct_id;
    }
}
```